# Python with statement

Tags: python, with-statement

I'm reading [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and trying to make some examples. But it's not really clear to me now. Especially because I have an error:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 'f'
... 
>>> with f(): # or as f
...     print f() # or f
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Indeed, the function has no method `__exit__`. So how do you use the `with` statement?

Comment: it's useful for files as it calls the `close` automatically on `__exit__`

Comment: What would you expect `with f(): print f()` to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the with statement with a function you can use the [contextlib.contextmanager](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html) decorator.

Example from the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html):

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def tag(name):
    print "<%s>" % name
    yield
    print "</%s>" % name

>>> with tag("h1"):
...    print "foo"
...
<h1>
foo
</h1>
```

Comment: The question was "How do you use the with statement?" not "Is there a library to use a with statement with functions?".  I don't know why this answer was accepted.

Comment: @ zoogleflatt Because it answer OP X problem http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem :)